# OpenGL ES 2.0 weird bug while drawing meshes

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I've been working on rendering mechanics for an app and everything seemed to be fine until I started working on the light system and got weird artifacts. First I thought it was just something wrong with the calculation of normals, however after having no success, I tried to render it without the light system, but changing the color of each vertex. Similar effects have been produced, even on other meshes.

This is the draw method and the method which enables GL stuff (I already tried switching the culling face, the front face, disabling the depth test, but no difference).

http://textuploader.com/5yeyu

This is the output of printing out the components of the vbo (it is a FloatBuffer) object (mvbo is a handle), the output of printing out the components of the ibo (it is a ShortBuffer) object and the original OBJ file.

VBO is in format (position[X,Y,Z], normal[X,Y,Z], texture[X,Y])

http://textuploader.com/5yeyv

Here are some screenshots of the cube rotating around the Z and Y axis:

[image: one]
[image: two]
[image: three] 
[image: four]
[image: five]

Comment: This looks like you just don't have a working depth test. Without the code, nobody can know, but I'd bet on either not requesting an appropriate pixel format/visual which actuallly contains a depth buffer, or simply not enabling it at all.

Comment: Well, as it turns out, I'm an idiot. You were indeed right. Even though I did create a method for initializing OpenGL stuff such as enabling the depth test, I forgot to actually call the method.